# Syntax error using Plot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, warning-messages, syntax

[image]
Why is the error coming and what should I do to resolve it
[image]
The code is

```
sol1=DSolve[{2*y'[r]+r*y''[r]==-.262468*(-13.60r+14.3996)*y[r],
  y[0.0001]==1,y'[30]==0},y[r],r]


Plot[ Evaluate[y[r]/ sol1],{r,.000000001,.000001}]
```

Comment: Note that sol1 and sol are 2 different variables.

Comment: @DanielHuber i changed it but now this is coming

Comment: when i used Plot[ Evaluate[y[r]/. sol1],{r,.000000001,.000001}] still error was coming

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code as text, not an image, so others can copy/paste and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Use `DSolveValue` instead so you don't have to muck around with replacement rules.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Note also that writing `y[r]/ sol1` is not the same as `y[r]/. sol1`

Answer (score 2):

Your code contains: ry''[r]. You need a space between r and y.

But this does not solve your problem. DSolve seems not able to solve this. Maybe there is no closed form solution.

Trying to use NDSolve indicates that the system is unstable. The reason is that y'[30] is too far out,  y'[10] will work.

```
sol = y /. 
  NDSolve[{2 y'[r] + r  y''[r] == -.262468*(-13.60 r + 14.3996)*y[r] ,
      y[0.0001] == 1, y'[10] == 0}, y, {r, .000000001, 10}][[1]]

Plot[sol[r], {r, .000000001, .0001}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`DSolve` is an exact solver, and exact solvers sometimes cannot solve equations with inexact (floating-point) coefficients because round-off error makes things that should be equal or cancel fail to do so.  Use exact input and the system can be solved (after all, it's linear).

```
sol1 = DSolve[
    Rationalize@{
      2*y'[r] + r*y''[r] == -.262468*(-13.60 r + 14.3996)*y[r],
      y[0.0001] == 1, y'[30] == 0},
    y, r];

Plot[Evaluate[y[r] /. sol1], {r, .000000001, .0001}]
```

[image]

Generic solution, followed by specialization to OP's case:

```
sol2 = DSolve[
   {2*y'[r] + r*y''[r] == c*(m r + b)*y[r], y[r1] == 1, y'[r2] == 0},
   y, r];

Block[{c, m, b, r1, r2},
 c = -.262468;
 m = -13.60;
 b = 14.3996;
 r1 = 0.0001;
 r2 = 30;
 Plot[Evaluate[y[r] /. sol2], {r, .000000001, .0001}]
 ]
```